# Networking: When does a packet begin propagating?

Tags: networking

Does a whole packet have to be on the wire before it begins propagating or does propagation begin as soon as one bit is transmitted to the wire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When packet is handed over to the network card by the driver, it is held in TX-Buffer. Once packet is ready to be transmitted, each bit of the packet is converted to a corresponding electrical signal on wire (in case of wired networking) by the network card.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't answer the question. I understand that bits are transmitted but do they propagate immediately upon transmission or does the whole packet need to be transmitted first.

Comment: "Propagation" starts as soon as the bit is converted to electrical signal. And there is no such thing as "whole" packet transmission. Every thing is transmitted serially.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  By "whole" packet transmission, I mean that every bit that the packet consists of is on the wire.